# Prime factors of a number without using a flag variable?

Tags: c

I tried finding prime factors of a number without using a flag variable but I don't know what's the fault in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num, i, j;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {

        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    printf("%d", i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a 'flag' variable? Please clarify

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like telling us what happens when you run your program? What input do you give your program (or better yet hard-code it into the program)? What output do you expect? What output do you actually get?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/dhxq65qKG

Comment: I think to print the factors of i you need to print the value of `j`, and not the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

You have to print values that are factor of `num` and prime.

In your code you are printing factors of `num`, but not prime by printing `i` after seeing that a `j` that divids `i` exists.

Instead of that, you should check for all candidates of `j` and print `i` after seeing all `j`s tested don't divide `i`.

Also you may want to add some delimiters between the factors to print.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num, i, j;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {

        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    break; /* stop iteration because a factor is found */
                }
            }
            if (j > i / 2) /* check if the iteration ended not by finding factor but by checking all candidates */
            {
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach feels a bit convoluted.  Perhaps just do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        unsigned num = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 137;
        int count = 0;
        printf("%d = ", num);
        for( unsigned i = 2; i <= num; i++ ){
                while( num % i == 0 ){
                        printf("%s %d", count++ ? " *" : "", i);
                        num /= i;
                }
        }
        printf(" ( %d factor%s )\n", count, count == 1 ? "" : "s");
        return 0;
}
```